# Trouble with nested shiny module responding to action button click

Tags: r, shiny

I am having problems getting nested shiny modules with action buttons to respond.

I want the nested module to print to the console when clicked. I created a toy example to illustrate the problem.

```
library(shiny)

ui_2 <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(ns('go'), 'go')
}
server_2 <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent(input$go, print('working!'))
  })
}

ui_1 <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    ui_2(ns('two'))
  )
    
  
}
server_1 <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    server_2(ns('two'))
  }) 
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  ui_1('one')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  server_1('one')
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you wrapped the ID inside `ns()` in the first module server, i.e. do `server_2("two")` instead of `server_2(ns('two'))`.

```
library(shiny)

ui_2 <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(ns("go"), "go")
}

server_2 <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$go, print("working!"))
  })
}

ui_1 <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    ui_2(ns("two"))
  )
}
server_1 <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    server_2("two")
  })
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  ui_1("one")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  server_1("one")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]